# Multiple APIs are called with (change) in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api

On selecting any date and hitting `enter` an API call should be made. And there's a `x` icon in the `input` on clicking it, it should call the API with date `01/01/12` Also this has feature like if you type `2/3` and hit `enter` it will automatically make it `02/03/20`. The problem is if the `input` is empty and if I hit `Enter` same API calls are made thrice.

But the feature should be like if you select a date then without hitting `Enter` an API call should be made. I can't just use change function because if `2/3` is typed and `Tab` is pressed then it will not adjust the date automatically and also multiple API calls on hitting `Enter`. Is there a way to stop multiple API calls?

`(change)="startDate($event)" (keydown.enter)="CallAPI($event)"`

```
    startDate(event) {
        if (event.target.value == '' || event.target.value == null)
            this.cutoverFilterApi(event)
    }
    CallAPI(event) {
        let data = event.target.value;
        if (data != '' && data != null && data != "NaN/NaN/NaN") {
            data = data;
        } else {
            data = "01/01/12";
        }
        this.httpService.getData('PATH' + data).subscribe((response: any) => {
            this.dateChangeData = response.results;
            this.rowData = response.results;
            this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
        });
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the last valid value and avoid request if it is the same.

Something like this,

```
lastDate = null; // <- variable to keep last value
CallAPI(event) {
    let data = event.target.value;
    if (data != '' && data != null && data != "NaN/NaN/NaN") {
        data = data;
    } else {
        data = "01/01/12";
    }
    // check if data is not the same as last request
    if (this.lastDate === data) {
        return;
    }
    this.lastDate = data; // <- update new request date
    this.httpService.getData('PATH' + data).subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.dateChangeData = response.results;
        this.rowData = response.results;
        this.gridApi.setRowData(this.rowData);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. The better way is to set `lastDate` as null in case of http error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
(dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"
```

instead of

```
(change)="startDate($event)" (keydown.enter)="CallAPI($event)"
```

I have an example of angular material datepicker, which will make your code easier.

[Reference link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/odrmqdenkrv)

I hope it is helpful for you. :)